# Digits android integration HTTP Error: 403 Forbidden, API Error: 239, User Message: Try Again?

Tags: android, twitter-digits

Hello all recently i was integrating digits by twitter in android for login users, now previously it was working fine but now i don't know what happened but after few login's it show this error

> HTTP Error: 403 Forbidden, API Error: 239, User Message: Try Again

Now can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong also can someone pls tell me that in consumer key and consumer secret do i have to pass dev.twiiter my app credentials OR fabrics consumer key and secret, this thing is really very confuing because in docs they mentoned twitter keys but on some stackoverflow questions people say to use digits keys ?? Also i am not extending my activity from Application would that cause any problem or not ??

my code is give below please tell me what i am doing wrong it will be really helpful for me

```
public class Signup_firststageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private AuthCallback authCallback;

public AuthCallback getAuthCallback(){
     return authCallback;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup_firststage);
    TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (b.getString("error") == null) {

} else {
    if (b.getString("error") != null && b.getString("error").equals("server_down")) {
        text.setText("Error 503 Please Try Again");
    } else {

    }
}
//Twitter

TextView tryagain = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tryagain);
tryagain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Digits.authenticate(new DigitsAuthConfig.Builder().withAuthCallBack(authCallback).withPhoneNumber("+918972745648").build());
    }
});
final TwitterAuthConfig authConfig =  new TwitterAuthConfig("agfjgD6wetDXdjfjuC4ywwoeD", "BshdjfjfwGz8WLaofkjfjsfjjsjsfhKpv60hQxni60oZwAu");
Fabric.with(getBaseContext(), new TwitterCore(authConfig), new Digits());
authCallback = new AuthCallback() {
    @Override
    public void success(DigitsSession session, String phoneNumber) {
        Log.d("digits", "success phoneNumber: " + phoneNumber);
        Log.d("digits", "session " + session.getPhoneNumber() + " " + session.toString() + " " + session.isValidUser() + " " + session.getAuthToken() + " " + session.getId());
        //    TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = TwitterCore.getInstance().getAuthConfig();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Signup_firststageActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait... ");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        progressDialog.show();
        TwitterAuthToken authToken = (TwitterAuthToken) session.getAuthToken();

        OAuthSigning oauthSigning = new OAuthSigning(authConfig, authToken);
        Map<String, String> authHeaders = oauthSigning.getOAuthEchoHeadersForVerifyCredentials();
        Log.d("digits", "authHeaders: 1" + authHeaders);
        Signup_MobileNumber_requestData(session.getPhoneNumber());
        Digits.getSessionManager().clearActiveSession(); // don't know should i write this here or not ??
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(DigitsException exception) {
        Log.d("digits", "failure");
        // Do something on failure
    }
};

DigitsAuthButton digitsButton = (DigitsAuthButton) findViewById(R.id.auth_button);
digitsButton.setCallback((this).getAuthCallback());
digitsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d("digits", "button click");

    }
});
```

}

Thank You in advance

Comment: We are getting the same issue:
E/Digits: HTTP Error: 403 Forbidden, API Error: 239

Answer (score 3):

This problem is occurred because of Key and Secret. I was trying to copy the values from Fabric dashboard and i got the same error.

It worked when i get the values from Fabric-Android Studio Plugin->Digits->Install->Apply

Comment: also you can get Twitter Key and Secret values from Fabric Dashboard. Go to fabric.com, select app and open Digits tab.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?